# Can vim syntax priorities be reversed?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Here is the entry for `:help syn-priority`.

```
PRIORITY                        *:syn-priority*

When several syntax items may match, these rules are used:

1. When multiple Match or Region items start in the same position, the item
   defined last has priority.
2. A Keyword has priority over Match and Region items.
3. An item that starts in an earlier position has priority over items that
   start in later positions.
```

It appears that rule `3` seems to override rule `1`.

**Is it possible to make rule `1` take precedence over rule 3?**

Here is a concrete example of the undesirable behavior. Using the following syntax file, it seems that `nTODO` has a higher priority than `boldme`.

```
syntax clear
syntax case match

syntax match nTODO /^\s*!!.*/ 
syntax match boldme /\*.\+\*/

highlight nTODO  ctermfg=Yellow
highlight boldme ctermfg=Red
```

Example input to match on:

```
This *line* has one word Red.
!!This line is completely yellow.
!!This line is also *completely* yellow, but I want one word to be red.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after the nested-match facility, see `:help syn-contains`

```
   :syntax match boldme /\*[^*]\+\*/
   :syntax match nTODO /^\s*!!.*/ contains=boldme
```

Comment: I still want the match on boldme *regardless* of whether it is contained, so it looks like I have to define the match for `innerBold` *twice*, once with the `contained` keyword and once without. I accept because it solves the problem, but please update if you know of way to do it without the redundancy.

Comment: Exactly how I missed this I'll leave to my neuropathologist, but it turns out the "contained" keyword isn't required.